# Center an image inside image frame with scribus

Tags: alignment, scribus

I have an image frame inside my document and I have set it up to scale the image down to fit within the frame however the image gets put on the left of the frame and not in the center.

[image]

How would I get this to position in the center of the frame? The alignment tools seem to only work with the frames themselves and not the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's not a good idea to put images in a frame without filling the whole frame.

The preflight verifier will give you a warning in such cases, because there is a risk that you miss wrong alignments when you start doing so.

The solution to your problem seems to be to slightly change your workflow, resize the frames to their content, and then use the guides and the alignment tool to place your frame.

Of course, through scripting you can get Scribus to help you center the image in the frame. [This one](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Align_an_Image_in_its_Frame) does it, but:

- I have not tried this specific script.
- You will need Tcl/Tk installed (of course it's easy to change the script do only do the image centering without using any dialog).